# Integration of UFT with LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner, hp-uft

How to integrate UFT scripts with LoadRunner Controller??Steps to Integrate HP UFT Scripts to Loadrunner Controller

Answer (score 0):

When adding a user group, in the dialog, select "GUI Scripts" from the "Files of type" drop down, then select your UFT script.

Comment: On doing that no such uft files on which i am working is being showing.Rest all files are showing but the file i.e,virtual user test file is not showing

Answer (score 0):

G R A P H I C A L
V I R T U A L
U S E R

Be sure you have

- Named Timing Records
- A graphical virtual user license
- An architectural understanding of why you must run full clients with an OS instance per virtual user
- Already answered the question of whether your application/business process/page/site is performant for a single user, and is functionally correct
- Built optimized scripts for performance testing and are not simply reusing functional test scripts
- Not engaged in a test design which suggests you can answer questions of load and functionality with one test execution.  You need to understand scalability for a single user before you can understand scalabilty for multiple users.